# Strange behavior of jar -C command: not all expected files included

Tags: java, jar

I am facing a problem while creating a jar. Details are:

```
[amulay@pugthesestock-dr Desktop]$ ll src/com/foo/bar/
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amulay amulay 421 Jul 17 11:40 Test1.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amulay amulay 125 Jul 17 11:40 Test1.java
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amulay amulay 421 Jul 17 11:40 Test2.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amulay amulay 125 Jul 17 11:39 Test2.java

[amulay@pugthesestock-dr Desktop]$ jar -cvf Test.jar -C src src/com/foo/bar/*.class
src/src/com/foo/bar/Test1.class : no such file or directory
added manifest
adding: com/foo/bar/Test2.class(in = 421) (out= 288)(deflated 31%)

[amulay@pugthesestock-dr Desktop]$ unzip -l Test.jar 
Archive:  Test.jar
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
        0  07-17-2013 11:47   META-INF/
       68  07-17-2013 11:47   META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
      421  07-17-2013 11:40   com/foo/bar/Test2.class
---------                     -------
      489                     3 files
```

The file Test2.class is getting added in jar but not Test1.class?

Comment: try removing the `src` from your class' file path

Answer (score 1):

The `-C` option will change into given folder before starting to tar the files.

Should be:

```
jar -cvf Test.jar -C src com/foo/bar/*.class
```

to create a "runnable" jar.

Comment: No luck...[amulay@pugthesestock-dr Desktop]$ jar -cvf Test.jar -C src com/foo/bar/*.class
src/com/foo/bar/*.class : no such file or directory
added manifest

Comment: You have probably under src another src where is only Test2.class but not Test1.class.

Comment: If not, show us the full directory structure under the current working directory when you execute `jar -cvf `

Comment: [amulay@pugthesestock-dr Desktop]$ ls -lR src
src:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 3 amulay amulay 4096 Jul 17 14:13 com

src/com:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 3 amulay amulay 4096 Jul 17 11:37 foo

src/com/foo:
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 2 amulay amulay 4096 Jul 17 11:40 bar

src/com/foo/bar:
total 16
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amulay amulay 421 Jul 17 11:40 Test1.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amulay amulay 125 Jul 17 11:40 Test1.java
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amulay amulay 421 Jul 17 11:40 Test2.class
-rw-rw-r-- 1 amulay amulay 125 Jul 17 11:39 Test2.java